# How to customize existing TFS 2015 Build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, devops, build-definition

I am trying to customize a Build that is created using UI in `TFS 2015`. My requirement is the TFS build should be in Failed state if there are any warnings in the solution that is being built as a part of the `TFS Build`.

I tried to follow these steps : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551(v=vs.120).aspx#template_create
But the step 3 which suggest that the `Edit Definition` will allow to download the existing build is not happening. When i click on Edit definition it opens up in the Browser and allows OOTB editing.
[image]

I tried this with VS 2015 on local machine. How can i achieve this? Is there a reference to path on the server where i can find the TFS Build definition?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a reference to path on the server where i can find the TFS
>   Build definition

IIRC it's in the database since you're using XAML buidl definitions and not the VSO 'scripted' styled build definitions. You'd have to pull them out of the TFS Configuration database (maybe another one, I forget).

> TFS build should be in Failed state if there are any warnings in the
>   solution

The way I would try to implement this is to edit the msbuild parameters in the build definition and fail the build on warnings. Which might be possible with: TreatWarningsAsErrors msbuild property